# codepen not responding on 'Run', error message token

Tags: javascript, codepen

I am trying to practice algorithms on Codepen, however whenever I press 'Run' to intiate the code, which in this case is a simple 'console.log("hello")' I get the error message in console shown below (see image).

[image]

The Javascript settings are as they have always been whenever I practice algorithms but for some reason this is now happening every time I hit 'Run' and nothing is responding.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks for the help

Comment: why don't you use your own browser to practice algorithms ?

Comment: This isn't really the type of question for StackOverflow, but, are you logged in to CodePen with a 3rd party provider account such as GitHub or Facebook? If so, log out and back in again to see if that resolves this.